# Access multiple promises data in AngularUI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use the `$q` service to resolve multiple promises using the `$q.all()` function with AngularUI router but for some reasons this fails or it's not working as expected.

This is part of my configuration file that contains the `$stateProvider`:

```
.state('home.team',
{
    url : '^/team',
    views : {
        'main' : {
            templateUrl : ConfigProvider.path.views + '/segment/home/team.html',
            controller : 'SegmentHomeTeamCtrl',
            resolve : {
                promiseData : function(ResolveService) { return ResolveService.resolveHomeTeam(); }
            }
        },
        'subMenu' : {
            templateUrl : ConfigProvider.path.views + '/menu/home/team.html'
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the `resolveHomeTeam` function located in the `Resolve` service:

```
function resolveHomeTeam()
{
    var promises = [];
    promises.push($q.defer());
    UserService.team('me', function(data)
    {
        promises[0].resolve(data);
    }, function()
    {
        promises[0].reject();
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

As you can see in this case I'm pushing just one promise into the array and I know for sure that it's being resolved.

Since the only promise is resolved, shouldn't also the promise returned by `$q.all()` resolved? And shouldn't `promiseData` data be injected into the `SegmentHomeTeamCtrl` controller?

If I try to output `promiseData` inside `SegmentHomeTeamCtrl` controller I get the whole promise back containing also the actual data returned by the server buy for some reasons I cannot access it.

Comment: What is `UserService.team()`? Does it return a promise?

Comment: It just performs an API call to the server and has some callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are putting a *deferred* into your array, not a promise.

And on that note, deferreds are quickly going out of fashion. The preferred way to make a promise (and which is consistent with the ES6 APIs) is to use a [promise constructor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor):

```
function resolveHomeTeam() {
    var promises = [];

    promises.push($q(function (resolve, reject) {
        UserService.team('me', resolve, reject);
    }));

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Note how this also makes your code quite a bit cleaner.

You could also combine this all into one statement if you wanted to:

```
function resolveHomeTeam() {
    return $q.all([
        $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            UserService.team('me', resolve, reject);
        })
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem and made things easier for me. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing almost everything correctly: you are returning a promise generated by `$q.all` and you are further returning it in the `resolve`.

The bug is that you are not creating an array of promises, but rather you pushed a deferred object into the array.

So, change it like so:

```
var promises = [];
var teamDefer = $q.defer();
promises.push(teamDefer.promise);

UserService.team('me', function(data)
{
   teamDefer.resolve(data);
}, function()
{
   teamDefer.reject();
});
```

Then you can return `$q.all()` (as you do):

```
return $q.all(promises);
```

**Slightly off-topic**:

`promiseData` is incorrectly named, in my opinion, that may indicate a misunderstanding. You should name the variable as the name of the result of you will get. This is what will be injected into your controller, which would not care whether it came from a promise or not. So, probably better to name it `team` (or something like that)

Comment: I found your answer very useful but I decided to chose the other one simply because it was using the promise constructor (that I was unaware of). Thank you anyway for your time and kindness.